# Close votes for "Not enough information, no return"?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, flagging

I've started using "Too localised" for voting to close on questions that don't have enough information, and where the OP hasn't returned.

Is this appropriate? Should I be using the "Low quality" flagging method instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest, rather than "Too Localized", that your close reason would probably fit as "Not A Real Question". If the case is that the question does not contain enough detail, by author absence or otherwise, it is incomplete and cannot be reasonably answered, which falls in line with the description of Not A Real Question.

I might recommend, though, that when using Not A Real Question, that you might consider accompanying it with a comment explaining that it's specifically the incompleteness that is an issue.

Comment: Not a bad idea, however I was hoping we could agree on a standard method to avoid having to add explanatory comments. Especially since this is such a common issue.

Comment: You don't *have* to supply comments. The "incomplete" and "cannot reasonably be answered" are all in there, so you can always go by that. It's up to the closer whether or not they feel the need to go the extra yard, especially in the case of a user who *is* absent, you may simply elect not to say anything.

Comment: I recommend adding a comment if the user has been active in the last month or two, as it's possible they have an answer. You could either request what information the question needs to be answerable, or ask them if they've since found the solution that they can leave as an answer.

Comment: Not a real question sounds good to me!
@Alex: Yeah I've been trying to ask people for more information. Then, if I go back to a question, see my comment, and the user still hasn't replied, I know I can close the question.

Comment: @ccomet: I misunderstood originally: I thought you were referring to the "Other" flag's comments (that the mod sees).

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, everyone should use the vote to close. This way, the community plays a larger role in site cleanup.

The flags should be reserved for situations that require more immediate attention.

Comment: P.S. I'd be interested in other people's thoughts about this.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, although there needs to be a general community consensus for this to work.

Comment: @Stuart Mods can see what questions people are flagging to close so we can swoop in, assess, and assist if required! Please don't use flags if you have voting powers.

Comment: Is there an easy way for us to see what posts have votes to close?  I'm more than willing to help close dead posts if I can.

Comment: @Kit: Do I have the madness hamsters, or did the 'Vote to Close' rep requirement just jump up a huge quantity?

Comment: @StuartPegg: Yeah, since we launched, I believe the rep requirements were increased.